# Search in a list for characters

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ironpython

I have done a large amount of searching but cannot find what I am after. I am using Iron Python.

I have a large list of strings (MyList) that I have extracted and I would like to see if there are values that contain the Items in the SearchStrings Dictionary. The searchStrings Dictionary could have over 500 items within.

```
MyList = ["123steel","MylistConcrete","Nothinginhere","45","56","steel","CONCRETE"]
SearchStrings = {'concrete' : 'C','CONCRETE' : 'C','Steel' : 'S', 'STEEL' : 'S'}
```

I need to return the index and then matching code from the SearchString.

i.e If we find `'MylistConcrete'` i will know the index '1' and can return `'C'`

I hope this makes sense to everyone. Let me know if you need any clarification

Thanks in Advance,

Geoff.

Comment: What's your desired output for the *specific example* in your question?

Comment: What about treatment of lower / uppercase. I.e. `Concrete` is not in `SearchStrings.keys`, but `concrete` and `CONCRETE`.

Comment: Ideally I would like to ignore the case, perhaps change everything to lowercase

Comment: the specific scenario is that a user may input something like 'concrete' or 'CONC' or 'CONCRETE' etc and I want to return the value 'C' in a new list that I can pass back as the value. I guess that a dictionary is the best way to store these matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over your items in `MyList` and check for every item (lowercase) if any of the dict's (lowercase) keys is in it. Then replace.
This assumes that you don't have different values for identical words as keys (except for lower- / uppercase difference)

```
my_list = ["123steel", "MylistConcrete", "Nothinginhere", "45", "56", "steel", "CONCRETE"]
search_strings = {'concrete': 'C', 'CONCRETE': 'C', 'Steel': 'S', 'STEEL': 'S'}

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for k, v in search_strings.items():
        if k.lower() in my_list[i].lower():
            my_list[i] = v
            break   # avoids completing the loop if first item is found
print(my_list)
```

The result is

```
['S', 'C', 'Nothinginhere', '45', '56', 'S', 'C']
```

Comment: that looks great, I shall try this.

Comment: perfect, works just great. Thank you very much. I need to spend a lot more time learning this stuff!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd suggest you to use `string.lower()` to eliminate case dependencies in the search. This will make your dictionary smaller and more manageable.

Then you can use a simple map function to create a new array with your values while preserving the index (or alter the original should you require that).

```
MyList = ["123steel","MylistConcrete","Nothinginhere","45","56","steel","CONCRETE"]
SearchStrings = {'concrete' : 'C', 'steel' : 'S'}

def check_search_strings(x):
    for k, v in SearchStrings.items():
        if k in x.lower():
            return v
    return None

indexes = list(map(check_search_strings, MyList))

print (indexes)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for m in MyList :
    for k in SearchStrings :
        if k.lower() in m.lower() :
            print 'found', k, 'in', m, 'result', SearchStrings[k]
```